# loading different offline images (default images ) in NetworkImageview Volley android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, gridlayoutmanager

**What I have**

I have `GridLayoutManager Recyclerview` which has **positions 0,2,5,7 fixed** with custom images (relative layout converted to bitmap **;)** ) , rest positions are filled with images from server using **volley's setImageUrl()**

**What I want**

I wanted the `GridLayoutManager Recyclerview` to show offline images from **my drawable folder** using  **setDefaultImageResId()** till the images from server loads

**My problem**

How do I set different `default images` even when there is no images from server **reason (when there is no data from server , the `GridLayoutManager Recyclerview` doesn't populates cells)** , still I wanted to show default images (mini 4 cells required)

**temporary trick I did**

I upploaded my 4 defaults images in dummy server **to force `GridLayoutManager Recyclerview` to generate cells** and showing it using **volley's setImageUrl()**

**My expected result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that Volley has the option to display a default image and a image if an error has occurred.

```
NetworkImageView niv = (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.niv);
if(url.length() > 0) 
    niv.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
niv.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable._default);
niv.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.error);
```

Comment: I knew this , but default image comes to action when I have data from server . What If I don't I data still I wanted to show Default Image ?

Comment: According to the documentation setDefaultImageResId "Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the attempt to load it completes", so I suppose that if you don't get an image from your server the default image will be displayed, no?

Comment: I i don't get image from server , my Recyclerview doesn't even populates the cell , then how do I display DefaultImages ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** for loading the images from the server. Using Picasso, you can determine an image to be shown in case of a network error, or if no data is available.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).error(R.drawable.error_or_defaultimage).into(R.id.imageview,callback) ;
```

[Here's a tutorial on using Picasso.](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android)